# How to create Yahoo Messenger Client in Android?

Tags: android

I am trying to create Yahoo messenger client in Android, and i got Openymsg api to implement that.This is small snippet of my code

```
        Session session=new Session();
        session.login("Email Id", "password");
```

But this code is throwing UnknownHost Exception in "scs.msg.yahoo.com".I dont know how to fix this.If any body knows it please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Have you trapped the packets to see if they give you any exception details? Try to use wireshark or tcpdump to view the entire session.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you haven't included the `INTERNET` permission.

Add this to your [AndroidManifest.xml](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/security.html#permissions):

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Does it only happen in the emulator?

I've had the emulator somehow "drop" the connection on occasion. Restarting the emulator always fixes it..

Comment: Still the exception is coming

Comment: Are you behind a firewall? If so, messenger services may be blocked.. Try to ping scs.msg.yahoo.com from your commandline.

Comment: I done as you told.It is giving the response as ,

Pinging scs.msg.yahoo.com [68.180.217.7] with 32 bytes of data:

Reply from 68.180.217.7: bytes=32 time=360ms TTL=49
Reply from 68.180.217.7: bytes=32 time=1050ms TTL=49
Reply from 68.180.217.7: bytes=32 time=352ms TTL=49
Reply from 68.180.217.7: bytes=32 time=358ms TTL=49

Ping statistics for 68.180.217.7:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 352ms, Maximum = 1050ms, Average = 530ms

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this? cn.scs.msg.yahoo.com adding cn subdomain in scs.msg.yahoo.com

http://jasoet.wordpress.com/2009/06/30/pidgin-tidak-konek-ke-yahoo/