# Integration of Yahoo Messenger and Gtalk in Android application

Tags: android, google-talk, yahoo-messenger

I need to build a chat application in my Android application in which I want to integrate Yahoo Messenger and Gtalk. I searched many tutorials on the net but I'm unable to find a proper tutorial. Can someone suggest me a good tutorial/example on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For gtalk can try this [word-press article](http://davanum.wordpress.com/2008/12/29/updated-xmpp-client-for-android/)

may helpful
This android application aims at enabling you to control your phone through gtalk. It can be useful for those who prefer typing sms on a real keyboard.

here is [TalkMyPhone](http://code.google.com/p/talkmyphone/) example app

Comment: http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2008/12/30/using-google-talk-from-java-example/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9304136/google-talk-api-integrations-with-android-app

Comment: not fro android but may helpful http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch01s04.html

Answer (score 0):

## for gtalk

1.you need XMPP Java API on Android read docs [here](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/xmpp/overview#Sending_Chat_Messages) and [here](https://developers.google.com/talk/)

2.short [example here](http://www.andrejkoelewijn.com/wp/2008/12/30/using-google-talk-from-java-example/)

3.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977260/android-gtalk-api) SO thread helpful for gtalk api

## for yahoo messanger

1. check Yahoo! Messenger IM API docs [here](http://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch02s03.html#apinotificationmanagement)
2. also [this tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1878877/how-to-create-yahoo-messenger-client-in-android) may help you

let me know if it helps?